# Why is my OnClick for this ImageView not working?

Tags: android

I really have no clue why this is not working, Ive been trying it all night.. The `ImageView` should subtract score when I click on it. I also tried logging it but without success.. Is it maybe because of my animation interfering somehow?

This is my entire XML

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/timer1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Test" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/score1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Score:" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgview1"
    android:layout_width="83dp"
    android:layout_height="131dp"
    android:clickable="true"  
    android:onClick="PeanutClick" 
    android:src="@drawable/lil_peanut"/>
```

This is my source code

```
public class GameView extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
MediaPlayer backgroundMusic;
TextView mTextField;
TextView mScoreField;
Point size = new Point();
Display display;
ImageView image;
int score = 0;

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.gameviewlayout);
    int l;
    mTextField = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timer1);
    mScoreField = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.score1);
    image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgview1);
    image.setOnClickListener(this);
    TranslateAnimation moveLefttoRight = new TranslateAnimation(0, 200, 0,
            0);
    moveLefttoRight.setDuration(5000);
    moveLefttoRight.setFillAfter(true);
    moveLefttoRight.setRepeatCount(-1);
    moveLefttoRight.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE);
    image.startAnimation(moveLefttoRight);
    new CountDownTimer(45000, 1000) {

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            mTextField.setText("Seconds Remaining: " + millisUntilFinished
                    / 1000);
        }

        public void onFinish() {
            mTextField.setText("done!");
        }
    }.start();
    display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    display.getSize(size);
    int width = size.x;
    int height = size.y;
    backgroundMusic = MediaPlayer
            .create(GameView.this, R.raw.gallery_music);
    backgroundMusic.start();

}

public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v.getId() == R.id.imgview1)
        Log.i("MB2", "Touchy touchy!");
    PeanutClick();
}

public void PeanutClick() {
    score = score - 100;
    mScoreField.setText("Score: " + score);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
    backgroundMusic.release();

}
```

Edit; The posted solution does not work. I updated the code with my entire XML and current code.

Comment: What API version are you targeting in your manifest?

Comment: Is your code executing PeanutClick? If you put a breakpoint on the first line (score = score -100) does it get hit?

Comment: What kind of layout is gameviewLayout.xml?  Is it a framelayout by chance?  There are some layout situations where your object will be obscured and not the frontmost thing in its area.  Some people have solved the problem by moving the object (your ImageVew in this case) further down in the layout, so it will be above other conflicting items.

Comment: Thanks for the response guys. I'm targeting 16. It is not executing the code, and it is a linear layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out thanks to all your help. 
The `onClick` was working all along, but only on the original position of the image.

```
<ImageView
android:id="@+id/imgview1"
android:layout_width="83dp"
android:layout_height="131dp"
android:clickable="true"  
android:onClick="PeanutClick" 
android:src="@drawable/lil_peanut"/>
```

With this XML, only the top left corner is clickable. I fixed it by changing     `android:layout_width="83dp"`to     `android:layout_width="fill_parent"`

Comment: What about the `layout_height`? Did that have to get changed as well?

Comment: if you change layout_height to fill the parent, the entire screen both horizontal and vertical will be click able.

Answer (score 1):

```
public void PeanutClick(View view) {
    score = score - 100;
    mScoreField.setText("Score: " + score);
}
```

The public method should take in a View parameter.

Comment: Thanks, this made it work, but only on the original position of where the image is. But atleast the onclick is working, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure how the clicking properties work on the XML. But you can do it in your Java file with something along the lines of...

```
public class GameView extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
   ImageView iv;
   // whatever else

   public void onCreate(...)
   {
       // ...
       iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
       iv.setOnClickListener(this);
   }

   public void onClick(View v)
   {
       if (v.getId() == R.id.imageView1)
          PeanutClick();
   }
}
```

Comment: Hi cskoala. Also after implementing these functions, it still does not register any onclick events... This is my full code; http://paste2.org/mHBUg71v

Comment: aaaaaaaaaargh its driving me nuts